# select radio button values multiple times Angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, radio-button

I have multiple radio buttons created out of a list of variables and I want to be able to select any one button and be able to select it repeatedly.
The code that I have written lets me select options only once, when I select a option which was already selected before, it does not let me. 
Please help me with this.
I have pasted below only the part of my code which is relevant to my question. Please disregard any syntax errors and suggest if this can be achieved in any other better way.

```js
$scope.protocols = ['L3 Sanity', 'L2 Sanity', 'ROUTING', 'STP', 'VLAN', 'Interface Scale', 'VLAN SCALE'];
$scope.reserveTB = function selectPT(PT) {
     $scope.option=PT;
      };
```

```html
<h3>Choose the protocol suite:</h3>
<label ng-repeat="protoName in protocols">
<input type="radio" name ="PTCL" 
       ng-model="selectedPT" value="{{protoName}}" 
       ng-change='selectPT(selectedPT)'>{{protoName}}<br>
</label>
<div>
<h3>Selected option:</h3>
<br>{{option}}
</div>
```

Comment: Why do you want to select things repeatedly - what are you trying to achieve with that. Once you select an option, you should be done?

Comment: The requirement is such that, once an option is selected, a corresponding service will be generated. Once this service is done executing, the user should be able to start that service again.

Comment: So add a button which does that - far more clear and usable

Comment: so, in the place where I have written "$scope.option=PT;", I am actually starting a service in the backend  by generating a http request. I hope the requirement is clear now.

Comment: I cannot have that. Because when a protocol is chosen, I am displaying a list of compatible devices on which the service should be executed. Hence, I need that value from radio buttons and not just a button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your qstn you have multiple `radio buttons` options, but want to select 1 at any time and want to de-select it also.
For such cases ideally, `checkboxes` seems to be right choice.

But if you need to do it with radio buttons then see below code.

also, your `ng-model` should be `hierarchical` *(must have dot(.) in it.),*  because `ng-repeat` creates new `child scope.` and your property overidden by new scope.

**Working code:**

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.valChanged = false;
  $scope.protocols = ["L3 Sanity", "L2 Sanity", "ROUTING", "STP", "VLAN", "Interface Scale", "VLAN SCALE"];
  $scope.data = {selectedPT: $scope.protocols[0]};

  $scope.toggle = function() {
    if (!$scope.valChanged) {
      $scope.data.selectedPT = "";
    }
    $scope.valChanged = false;
  }
  $scope.changefn = function(){
    $scope.valChanged = true;
    // you have updated value of $scope.data.selectedPT, 
    // and can do watever you want, like service call
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.2/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <h3>Choose the protocol suite:</h3>
    <div ng-repeat="protoName in protocols track by $index">
       <input type="radio" name ="PTCL{{$index}}" 
       ng-model="data.selectedPT" 
       ng-value="protoName" 
       ng-change="changefn()"
       ng-click="toggle()">{{protoName}}
   </div>
    <div>
      <h3>Selected option : {{data.selectedPT}}</h3>      
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thanks a lot @anoop . You saved my day.

Comment: @AmithB:  glad to help you..:), pls upvote and  [mark it answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) as well

Answer (score 0):

`ng-change` function name should be `selectPT`

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("ctrl",function($scope){

$scope.protocols = ['L3 Sanity', 'L2 Sanity', 'ROUTING', 'STP', 'VLAN', 'Interface Scale', 'VLAN SCALE'];
$scope.selectPT = function (PT) { 
     $scope.option=PT;
};
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
 <h3>Choose the protocol suite:</h3>
<label ng-repeat="protoName in protocols">
<input type="radio" 
       ng-model="selectedPT" value="{{protoName}}" 
       ng-change='selectPT(selectedPT)'>{{protoName}}<br>
</label>
<div>
<h3>Selected option:</h3>
<br>{{option}}
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: like I said, I renamed the function name before pasting it here. In my original code, the function name is "reserveTB". Please ignore that error and suggest a solution for this problem.